# (IndexError: list index out of range) My for loop is giving me an error?

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, traceback

Here is my code:

```
import game, pygame, sys
from gameobjects import *
from imageloader import *




def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (800, 600) )
    background = Background("images/Nebula1.bmp", screen.get_width(), screen.get_height())
    letter1 = pygame.image.load("1.bmp")
    letter2 = pygame.image.load("2.bmp")
    letter3 = pygame.image.load("3.bmp")
    letter4 = pygame.image.load("4.bmp")
    letter5 = pygame.image.load("5.bmp")
    letter6 = pygame.image.load("6.bmp")
    letter7 = pygame.image.load("7.bmp")
    letter8 = pygame.image.load("8.bmp")
    letter9 = pygame.image.load("9.bmp")
    letter10 = pygame.image.load("10.bmp")
    Letters = [letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4, letter5, letter6, letter7, letter8, letter9, letter10]
    letter = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        screen.blit(background.image, (0,0))

        for i in Letters:
            screen.blit( Letters[letter], (330 + 14 * letter, 190) )
            letter += 1


        pygame.display.flip()
All the items in the Letters list are pygame.Surfaces retrieved through using pygame.image.load(). Every time I run this code, I get an error that looks like this:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 75, in <module>
        main()
      File "main.py", line 32, in main
        screen.blit( Letters[letter], ((330 + 14 * letter, 190)) )
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this happening? It seems perfectly valid to me. What am I doing wrong? What I want to do is paste each letter on the screen 14 pixels over from the last one, because each one is 14 pixels wide. Any help? (I am new to python so if I made a dumb mistake, forgive me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `letter = 0` for each iteration. Because its outside of the while loop, letter is only set to `0` on initialization. Afterwards it throws an `IndexError` as on the second iteration of the `for i in letters`, as `letter` is now equal to the length of the `letters` because of the last iteration!

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to safety and easily increment:

```
for i,val in enumerate(Letters):
        screen.blit( Letters[i], (330 + 14 * letter, 190) )
```

or alternatively, include `letter = 0` inside the while loop:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background.image, (0,0))

    letter = 0
    for i in Letters:
        screen.blit( Letters[i], (330 + 14 * letter, 190) )
        letter += 1
```

Comment: It ran, but I ran into another problem. When I run it, the letters don't really print to the screen, they just really quickly slide across it.... Do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Since these are two different questions, you should ask another one about the new issue. If my answer solved you first problem, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: What I meant was that the for loop doesn't do what it was supposed to do, that was what I wanted an answer to. That was the question, cuz I still have an error, just not the same error.

Comment: Where is the bad `for` loop in the question? Please don't edit away the error, how is anyone supposed to understand what this answer is fixing?

Comment: Oh oops sorry I was adding the rest of the code, I'll change the error back. It was in the copy paste.

Comment: In this answer, couldn't you use `val` instead of `Letters[i]`?

Comment: I still don't see the code that this answer is correcting. he's not starting `letter` at `1`. I looked back at the editing history, and the first version has `letter = 0`.

Comment: Yeah Im sorta confused too.

Comment: @Barmar for the above code to work you would have to set the `letter=0` inside the while loop. As it stands, it correctly iterates through `letters` the first time, then the second time its executed `letter = len(letters)` and you get an index error.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't notice that this loop was inside another loop.